# Flashing folder with question mark, spinning beachball when wakes up

Tags: sleep-wake, startup

My MacBook is acting weird recently. It starts to show flashing folder with question mark during bootup and spinning beach ball when it wakes up from a long sleep. When these happens, I will have to power it down, then it works perfectly again. They occurs quite frequent, about once in every 5 bootup/wakes up.

Running Lion 10.7.4, and I just replaced the HDD with a SSD 2-3 months ago. The problem starts to occur about a month ago.

I suspect it has something to do with the SSD, but I can't really pinpoint the exact problem. I'd already reselect the startup disc multiple times in system preferences.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Update: OWC just came back to me, telling me it's probably due to SATA incompatibility and is offering me a refund. The refund is 50 dollars less than the purchase price (current value price, he said) and I am responsible for the shipping cost. I am considering if I should just keep it, as I am not located in the states and shipping back is really an hassle, plus the cost.

Comment: What brand is the SSD?  I've heard that the Crucial branded SSDs beach-ball when waking from sleep.

Comment: It's a OWC Mercury Pro 6G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Folder with a question mark on boot [indicates](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1440) that it could not find a bootable partition. There is something flaking with your drive, get it diagnosed, repaired, or replaced, ***ASAP***.

Comment: If the drive is dying, I should expect my computer to hang every now and then isn't it? But apparently the disk only have problem during boot up and waking up. If I don't put it to sleep, I can use the computer perfectly for up to 12 hours without any abnormality.

Comment: But if you put it to sleep, you have problems waking it back up. (Hint: The problem occurs after powering down the drive.)

Answer (score -1):

The folder with a question mark means the built in program the you cannot delete could not find a operating system on your drive.

You should make sure the the hard drive is properly installed in the computer and you might wanna run the Disk Repair utility on it to make sure that it is not a problem with the operating system.

Comment: How does this differ from other answers?